# Dependency testing and parallel compilers

Tags: compilers, parallel-computing, loops

I currently study well known dependency testing for automatic loop parallization from parallel compilers (ZIV, SIV, MIV, Single Variable Constraint, Multiple Variable Constraint, Acyclic Test, Fourier - Motzkin variable elimination, Delta test, Lambda test, Range test, Omega test, power test and Constraint Matrix Test). Since these tests have been invented before 30+ years, I would like to know if they are still used in our days and if there are additional important such tests, that I have to study. Furthermore, I would like to know which are the most commonly used parallel compilers and which of the above (or other tests), they use for dependency testing. I noticed that the great majority of the related papers at least those describing the fundamental stuff are 30+ years old and the recent publications concern more technical and special cases.